# How to give each div created from setInterval an id starting from 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question might have been answered a few times, but I cannot seem to get it to work in my code. For everyone that is willing to help thank you.

I have an object that creates a rectangle on screen then I run setInerval to recreate the rectangle on the screen in order for many rectangles to be shown one after the other on screen.

The problem: I need to give each rectangle an ID, i don't know much about jquery and if I implement attr on .block for jquery it changes all the id's of all the divs.

I want each new div that is created to have its own id example id=block1 then the next div will be id=block2 and so on and all of them will be of class block.

```
var cHeight = window.innerHeight - 150; //size of block
var cWidth = window.innerWidth - 150; 

var Block = function(block) {
    this.block = document.createElement('div');
    this.block.className = 'block'; 


    document.body.appendChild(this.block);

}

Block.prototype.coordinates = function(top,left) {
    this.block.style.top =  top + 'px';
    this.block.style.left = left + 'px';
}

Block.prototype.size = function(width,height) {
    this.block.style.width = width + 'px';
    this.block.style.height = height + 'px';
}


function randomTop() {
    var i = Math.random();
    var y = (i * (cHeight - 0 + 1)) +0;
    var x = Math.floor(y);
    return x;
}

function randomLeft() {
    var i = Math.random();
    var y = (i * (cWidth - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    var x = Math.floor(y)
    return x;
}


function repeatBlocks() {
block1 = new Block();
block1.size(150,150);
block1.coordinates(randomTop(),randomLeft());

}

setInterval(repeatBlocks,1000);
```

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gustav1105/sb1vLs38/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sb1vLs38/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add var id = 1;

Then in the Block function add this: this.block.id = "block"+id++;

```js
var cHeight = window.innerHeight - 150; //size of block
var cWidth = window.innerWidth - 150; 

var id = 1;

var Block = function(block) {
 this.block = document.createElement('div');
 this.block.className = 'block'; 
  this.block.id = "block"+id++;
 
 
 document.body.appendChild(this.block);

}

Block.prototype.coordinates = function(top,left) {
 this.block.style.top =  top + 'px';
 this.block.style.left = left + 'px';
}

Block.prototype.size = function(width,height) {
 this.block.style.width = width + 'px';
 this.block.style.height = height + 'px';
}


function randomTop() {
 var i = Math.random();
 var y = (i * (cHeight - 0 + 1)) +0;
 var x = Math.floor(y);
 return x;
}

function randomLeft() {
 var i = Math.random();
 var y = (i * (cWidth - 0 + 1)) + 0;
 var x = Math.floor(y)
 return x;
}


function repeatBlocks() {
block1 = new Block();
block1.size(150,150);
block1.coordinates(randomTop(),randomLeft());

}

setInterval(repeatBlocks,1000);
```

```css
.block {
 position: absolute;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```